# JavaScript - Why doesn't the addition assignment operator work as expected?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm currently enhancing a website with a few animations.

I tried this code:

```
// Opacity is 0 in the beginning. Set 
//  in CSS. 
// 1. Parameter: Boolean - true if making the
//  element visible; false if making it vanish.
// 2. Parameter: Object

var changeOpacity = function(direction, element) {
  var css = element.style;
  var goStep = function(signedStep) {
    css['opacity'] += signedStep;
    changeOpacity(direction, element);
  };

  if (direction) {
    if (css['opacity'] < 1.0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        goStep(0.1);
      }, timeStep);
    }
  } else {
    if (css['opacity'] >= 0.1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
      goStep(-0.1);
  }, timeStep);
    } else {
      css['display'] = 'none';    
    }
  }
};
```

It haven't worked.

I wrote a few console.logs in the code: 'opacity' always stayed at 0.1 after the assignment.

What I expected was: 0.0 - 0.1 - 0.2 - 0.3 ...

Now I use this code:

```
// ...
var goStep = function(signedStep) {
  css['opacity'] = +css['opacity'] + signedStep;
  changeOpacity(direction, element);
};
// ...
```

Works fine. 
But I still wonder why using the combined assignment addition operator failed.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: CSS values are strings, comparing strings (althought they'd look like numbers) to numbers will give you unexpected results.

Comment: The value of `css.opacity` is a string. Adding to it therefore concatenates the strings. If the value of `signedStep` is such that the the resulting string is an invalid value, the assignment will be ignored. The `+` works because it coerces `css.opacity` to a number before adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`css['opacity']` is a string. If you add a number to a string, it will convert the number into a string and concat the two final strings.

```
css['opactity'] = 0.1
css['opacity'] += 0.5 // => "0.10.5"
```

Comment: I thought that too. But 'opacity' doesn't "grow" that way. Output from a console.log which I made: After: 0.1
Before: 0.1
After: 0.1
Before: 0.1
After: 0.1
Before: 0.1

Comment: The code I used: console.log('Before: %s', css['opacity']);
   css['opacity'] += signedStep;
   console.log('After: %s', css['opacity']);
   changeOpacity(direction, element);

Comment: Instead of "growing" it becomes overwritten everytime and you get an infinite recursion.

Comment: Try that in the google chrome console: `document.body.style['opacity'] = 0.5` then `document.body.style['opacity'] += 0.5` it will return "0.50.5", so as the value is invalid, it will not be changed. You can verify this by printing it again in the console: `document.body.style['opacity']`

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding string with Number, so in first case you are actually concatenating the values

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment

The second aproach works because you are converting `css['opacity']` to a number: `+css['opacity']`

Try this:

```js
    var test = "0.1",
    test2 = "0.1";
    signedStep = 0.1;

    test += signedStep;
    alert(test+" is a "+typeof test);
    test2 = +test2 + signedStep;
    alert(test2+" is a "+typeof test2);
```